# Yaml-cpp, old api to new api , operator >>

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

i would like to convert the following sentence, which is in Yaml-cpp old api format to the new api. how to convert  **doc["Meta"]["type"] >> type** to the new API, as operator >> is deleted in the new api. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
typedef std::string MyType; // I believe, that you're retrieving string
MyType x = doc["Meta"]["type"].as<MyType>();
```

Comment: What contains pointers? What is the type of `fout->x.color`? TBH you didn't provide enough information.